# T-SQL Getting the Last Friday Payday of the year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can calculate future pay dates with the following, knowing that 1/3/2013 was a pay day, and that we are paid every two weeks.  This code tells me that 12/20/2013 was a payday. That's accurate.

```
declare @StartDate datetime = '1/4/13'
declare @FromDate datetime = '12/15/' + cast(year(getdate()) - 1 as char(4))

select dateadd(day, 14*cast(datediff(day, @StartDate, @FromDate) / 14 + 1 as int), @StartDate)
```

What I *need* to do, is calculate the last payday of the year.  If I set @FromDate to 12/15/2013, this works, but I don't believe I can rely on that in cases where December is a three check month.  My preference is to set the FromDate to 12/01/YYYY and get the last payday of that year, but I cannot seem to wrap my mind around how to pull that off.

How do I need to alter this to get the last Payday (always a Friday) of the year?

Thanks in advance for the forthcoming suggestions.

Comment: You know you can use `DATEADD(wk, @N, @FixedDate)` to find a date that's @N weeks after the @FixedDate, right? Wouldn't using a multiple of 52 for @N work? Then calculate that from the year difference from your fixed date.

Comment: Dates! Is 1/3/2013 = 2013-03-01 or 2013-01-03? I would expect from it being a payday, that it was a Friday and therefore was 2013-03-01, but then you say "12/20/2013" which is clearly a mm/dd/yyyy date???

Comment: Turophile, you're exactly right. Thanks!!  I've been flipping between 2013 and 2014.  1/4/13 and 1/3/14 were paydays. I mistyped that, but the code in the codebox is using 1/4/13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering that it will always be either the last friday or the penultimate friday of the year, this should work:

```
declare @startdate datetime='20140110'
declare @lastdayofyear datetime='20141231'
select 
case datediff(WEEK,@startdate,dateadd(day,6-datepart(w,@lastdayofyear)-7,@lastdayofyear)) % 2
when 0 then
dateadd(day,datepart(w,6-@lastdayofyear)-7,@lastdayofyear)
else
dateadd(day,datepart(w,6-@lastdayofyear)-14,@lastdayofyear)
end
```

Comment: Jayvee,  I like the approach, but it is giving me 12/22 which is a Tuesday.  I'll play with this and see if I can massage it, or beat it into submission.

Comment: just changed the determination of the week day (go to next friday after last day of the year and then subtract one week)

Comment: Jayvee, maybe I'm just overly obtuse, but I cannot get this code to work.  I've manipulated it all sorts of ways, and I keep getting the wrong date.  I'm getting Tuesdays.

Comment: Okay, I don't know why, but changing to this is giving me the correct date...
dateadd(day,datepart(w,2-@lastdayofyear)-7,@lastdayofyear)

Answer (score 1):

This could be done fairly easily with a [date dimension table](http://michaelmorley.name/how-to/create-date-dimension-table-in-sql-server).  Using the example in the link, a query would look like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Date] FROM DimDate 
WHERE DATEPART(dw, [Date]) = 6 --is Friday
    AND DATEPART(wk, [Date]) % 2 = 0--Is an even week
    AND YEAR([Date]) = YEAR(getdate())--Current year
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Comment: Even better is to use a Calendar table to store all dates AND the business-specific information attached to them, such as paydays, holidays, fiscal year, etc.

Comment: Good point.  I really wanted to just give an example of a query that would use a simple list of dates.  In fact, the `DATEPART` and `YEAR` functions are unnecessary in this since the table from the link inserts those values into columns as well, but I thought using the built in functions would give a better example.

Answer (score -1):

There are 52 weeks in a year.  Assuming one is paid bi-weekly as seems to be the case here, you can add 50 weeks to the start date to get the last date in the year.

```
declare @StartDate datetime = '1/4/13'
declare @FromDate datetime = '12/15/' + cast(year(getdate()) - 1 as char(4))

select dateadd(week, 50, @StartDate)

set @StartDate = '1/3/14'

select dateadd(week, 50, @StartDate)
```

First result is 12/20/2013.  Second result is 12/19/2014.

Comment: Fails in 2016, which has 53 Fridays.  This method returns the 51st

Comment: I don't think this works unless you allow for 27 fortnights every 4 years.